# Forms and Document Encryption

Tags: javascript, java, xml, forms, encryption

I am currently on co-op and was tasked with creating a form that, when submitted, would generate a document (.docx) containing the answers to the form and encrypt that document so that it may be sent back securely (the answers to the form are highly confidential).

What would be the best way of going about this? I'm quite lost and so any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to transfer the information safely would be to use HTTPS and ensure the server is running TLS version 1.2. Essentially you can do no better.